# Bash Function Space in single Argument

Tags: bash, function, console, arguments, spaces

I am new to the console, and attempting to write a function that will create a directory with the name of the directory being the function argument. This is my function so far:

```
clidir() {
    mkdir $1
}
```

Whenever I enter an argument with a space, it creates two directories. I have tried:

```
clidir "New Folder"
```

and

```
clidir New\ Folder
```

and they both create multiple directories.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You should almost *always* quote variables in shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-quote your argument to avoid word-splitting by shell

```
clidir() {
    mkdir "$1"
}
```

An excerpt from `man bash` page,

> Word Splitting
>
> The  shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion *that did not occur within double quotes* for **word splitting**. The shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as  field  terminators.   If  IFS  is unset, or its value is exactly , the default, then sequences of , , and  at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of IFS characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words.